# If $\frac{a_n}{1 + a_n} \longrightarrow 0$, how does this necessarily imply that $a_n\longrightarrow 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So we are given that $\frac{a_n}{1 + a_n} \longrightarrow 0$, as $n \longrightarrow \infty$. We also have that $a_n > 0$ for all positive integers $n$.

The solution states that this implies $a_n \longrightarrow 0$ as $n \longrightarrow \infty$.

I can see that if $\frac{a_n}{1 + a_n} \longrightarrow 0$, then either $a_n \longrightarrow 0$ or $(1+a_n) \longrightarrow \infty$.

Is the reason we can't have the second case (that $(1+a_n) \longrightarrow \infty$) because then this also implies that $a_n \longrightarrow \infty$ and so $\frac{a_n}{1 + a_n} \longrightarrow \infty$, contradicting our original assumption?

Comment: $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}=1-\frac{1}{1+a_n}\to 0$ if and only if $\frac{1}{1+a_n}\to 1$, i.e. $a_n\to 0$. If $a_n\to +\infty$, then $\frac{1}{1+a_n}\to 0\neq 1$.

Comment: @user263326: Why not make that an answer? :)

Comment: Thanks @user263326 ! If you would like to make than an answer I'll accept :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{a_n}}$.

This means that if the original statement is true, then $1+\frac{1}{a_n}$, or for the matter $\frac{1}{a_n}$ tends to infinity, which implies that $a_n$ tends to 0 since $a_n$ is positive.

Comment: Nice answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n=\frac{a_n}{1+a_n} = h(a_n)$, so $a_n = h^{-1}(x_n) = \frac{x_n}{1-x_n}$. But $h^{-1}$, the inverse of $h$ is continuos at $0$, and since $x_n \rightarrow 0$, then $a_n \rightarrow h^{-1}(0) = 0.$

Comment: This is a very nice and interesting idea imo, yet that $\;a_n\to h^{-1}(0)\;$ confused me. I'd rather use the lim notation + continuity at zero of $\;h^{-1}\;$ : $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}h^{-1}(x_n)=h^{-1}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\right)=h^{-1}(0)=0\;\;\;+1$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}=0$, there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\displaystyle n\ge N\implies\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}<\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$,

so $n\ge N\implies a_n<\epsilon$ and therefore $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.